# Can't use LINQ in Dynamic Query without errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dynamic, expression

I am trying to use LINQ on a dynamic list inside of its parent dynamic list.  The variable `c.characterBase.peerView.equipment` is of type `JArray`.  My goal is to make the `EquipmentList` property a list of strings, but it is currently a list of objects each with a string property.

```
dynamic dynamicData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
IEnumerable<dynamic> list = dynamicData.Response.data.characters;
var characters = list.Select(c => new CharacterModel
{
     ///other properties
     EquipmentList = c.characterBase.peerView.equipment
     .ToObject<List<Equipment>>().Select(p => new
      {

      })
});
```

Compile Error: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

```
dynamic dynamicData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
IEnumerable<dynamic> list = dynamicData.Response.data.characters;
Func<dynamic, string> function = equipment => equipment.itemHash;
var characters = list.Select(c => new CharacterModel
{
     ///other properties
     EquipmentList = c.characterBase.peerView.equipment
     .ToObject<List<Equipment>>().Select(function)//.Select("itemHash") fails using System.Linq.Dynamic as well
 });
```

Runtime Exception: 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Select'

Comment: I'm a little confused by this.  Shouldn't the signature for `function` be `Func<Equipment, string>`, not `Func<dynamic,string>`?

Comment: Probably, but I never get that far as I receive the runtime error saying "Select" is missing.

Comment: Which `Select` is it objecting to, do you know?  The one after the `ToObject` or the one on `list` a bit above it?

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if this is happening because `Select` is an extension method.  It doesn't actually belong to `IEnumerable` or `List`.  I believe it's the compiler that associates objects with their extension methods, not the runtime.

Comment: @AnnL. I believe you are correct there.  I'm just trying to find the best practice for this kind of thing as i'm sure it's possible.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're using dynamics so heavily.  If you were to go back to using static types, most of this difficulty would go away.  But, of course, I don't have the whole picture of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am using dynamic data b/c I do not have control of the source of the data.  I am making an API call to a third party web site, and they are returning me a huge chunk of JSON.  My goal is to create my own model with a fraction of that data, and then send that on to my client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use it don't use it. You can do this instead:

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(result);
JArray list = (JArray)data.SelectToken("Response.data.characters");
var characters = list.Select(c => new CharacterModel
{
    //other properties
    Other = c.Value<int>("otherProperty"),
    EquipmentList = ((JArray)c.SelectToken("characterBase.peerView.equipment"))
        .Select(p => p.Value<string>("itemHash")).ToList()
});
```

I personally do not see what benefit using dynamics brings to the table in this case, except confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I like your method much better!